# MongoDB-like JS library to store objects in client side indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, minimongo

Given the following `localStorage` code ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34gnxynd/4/)) :

```js
// my new information
var data = {character: "中", totalMistakes: 0};
var han  = data.character;

// create localStorage; Unpack, update, repackage knol
/* **** THIS IS THE SECTION TO CONVERT  **** */
localStorage.knol = '{}'; // create pseudo object, as string
var knol = JSON.parse(localStorage.knol)
knol[han] = data;
localStorage.knol = JSON.stringify(knol);

// Print to check if all went well.
console.log('data: ',data)
console.log('han: ',han)
console.log('knol: ',knol)
console.log('localStorage.knol: ',localStorage.knol)
console.log('localStorage.knol: ',JSON.parse(localStorage.knol))
console.log('localStorage.knol[han]: ',JSON.parse(localStorage.knol)[han])
```

At the end, `localStorage.knol` is :

```
{
  "中": {character: "中", totalMistakes: 0}
}
```

I'am looking for a Mongo-like js library to store data on client side indexedDB, with a syntax similar to MongoDB with which I'am already familiar.

**How to convert localStorage code above into Mongo-like IndexedDB library syntax so to store an object ?**

**EDIT:** I suggest minimongo, but any MongoDB-like library storing in indexedDB will do.

Comment: So, you're looking for a tutorial on how to use minimongo?

Comment: (That's available online. I would like to document on Stackoverflow various approach for **MongoDB-like indexedDB librairies**: minimongo, Dexie.js, ZangoDB, etc. A 101 kick starter. I'am at the beggining of my journey indeed. Feel free to submit something. All ways are welcome.)

Answer (score 2):

There is [a variety of librairies available to do that](http://docs.w3cub.com/dom/indexeddb_api/#See_also).

### Dexie.js

Using [Dexie.js and its API](http://dexie.org/docs/API-Reference) ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4hff3h3s/)) :

```
<!-- Include dexie.js -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dexie@latest/dist/dexie.js"></script>
<script>
var db = new Dexie('MyDatabase');

// Define a schema
db.version(1).stores({ knol: 'character, totalMistakes' });

// Open the database
db.open().catch(function(error) { alert('Uh oh : ' + error); });

// or make a new one
db.knol.put({ character: '中', totalMistakes: 8 });

// Find some old friends
var mistakes = db.knol.where('totalMistakes');
//mistakes.above(6).each (function (item) { console.log (item); });
mistakes.aboveOrEqual(0).each (function (item) { console.log (item)});
</script>
```

#### Minimongo

I don't recommend it, but [there is how to use it in web browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910939/how-to-make-minimongo-js-works-in-browser)

#### ZangoDB

(Exploration ongoing https://jsfiddle.net/vb92pecv/3/ )

Comment: ZangoDB seems to be abandoned... The author last commented on issues in the GitHub repo in 2019.